# Submit button to pass values to the database

Tags: php, submit, isset

I have written a php code that needs to insert record into a table whenever that page loads. I have written the below script and it doesnt insert anything into database.

```
<html>
<body>
<p align="center" ;">
        <input type="submit" name="ReportCons_Submit" value="SUBMIT" style="font-family:Arial; font-weight:bold; font-size:14; color:rgb(32,46,125); letter-spacing:4; text-align:center; background-color:rgb(204,204,204); margin-left:0;" size="200">
 </p>
 <p align="center"><font face="Arial" color="navy"><span style="font-size:10pt;">
 <?php
// This is in the PHP file and sends a Javascript alert to the client
$message = "Script begins";
echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('$message');</script>";

        if ( isset($ReportCons_Submit)) {

// This is in the PHP file and sends a Javascript alert to the client
$message = "Connecting to Oracle";
echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('$message');</script>";

                $conn = ocilogon("<USER>","<Pass>",'Local.com:1521/PRD');

                // Insert the date into mytable
                $s = oci_parse($conn,"insert into gem.my_table values ('EA','54896246','1521')");

                // Insert & commits
                $r = oci_execute($s);

                // The rollback does nothing: the data has already been committed
                // oci_rollback($conn);

// This is in the PHP file and sends a Javascript alert to the client
$message = "Data was committed";
echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('$message');</script>";
                echo "Data was committed\n";

 }
      ?>
    </span></font></p>
  </body>
</html>
```

The insert part, put separately is working fine, but when added with Submit option isnt working,

Please let me know what i am missing.

Comment: can you establish the connection successfully??
Try echoing $conn and check it is 1

Comment: Do you want the PHP segment to run after the submit button has been pressed or on this same page if the button has been pressed previously?

Comment: @Abhinav It is not getting into that loop itself.Once it gets in, it should pop up window showing, "Connecting to Oracle". The body of the if statement works perfecty, if put in a separate script. But not working in here.

Comment: @ElanHamburger PHP segment should run after the Submit is pressed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your not submiting anything coz there is no form to submit and you are checking a variable that is not defined instead of a value that is posted to form. made some changes to your code. hope it will work fine now

```
<html>
<body>
<p align="center" ;">
<form name="fff" method="get">
        <input type="submit" name="ReportCons_Submit" value="SUBMIT" style="font-family:Arial; font-weight:bold; font-size:14; color:rgb(32,46,125); letter-spacing:4; text-align:center; background-color:rgb(204,204,204); margin-left:0;" size="200">
 </p>
 <p align="center"><font face="Arial" color="navy"><span style="font-size:10pt;">
 </form>
 <?php
// This is in the PHP file and sends a Javascript alert to the client
$message = "Script begins";
echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('$message');</script>";

        if ( isset($_REQUEST['ReportCons_Submit'])) {

// This is in the PHP file and sends a Javascript alert to the client
$message = "Connecting to Oracle";
echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('$message');</script>";

                $conn = ocilogon("<USER>","<Pass>",'Local.com:1521/PRD');

                // Insert the date into mytable
                $s = oci_parse($conn,"insert into gem.my_table values ('EA','54896246','1521')");

                // Insert & commits
                $r = oci_execute($s);

                // The rollback does nothing: the data has already been committed
                // oci_rollback($conn);

// This is in the PHP file and sends a Javascript alert to the client
$message = "Data was committed";
echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('$message');</script>";
                echo "Data was committed\n";

 }
      ?>
    </span></font></p>
  </body>
</html>
```

https://www.w3schools.com/PhP/php_forms.asp will give you some idea